# Cordova app for Android, filetransfer plugin not downloading a file through https

Tags: android, cordova, https, video-streaming, file-transfer

I'm building a Cordova app for android, where i download pdf files and stream video hosted on a site with secure binding (https), but the download fails using the filetransfer plugin with code 3, and the video never play (using the html5 video tag ). I tried to modify the handling of SSL errors in the file 'CordovaWebViewClient.java' located in the platform folder, and tried whitelisting in the config.xml but nothing seems to work. 
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the certificate you use isn't trusted by the device, try setting the `trustAllHosts` param to `true`

```
fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    successCallback,
    errorCallback,
    true,
    options
);
```

Comment: Thank you @jcesarmobile, it worked on the PDF download. Do you suggest anything related to the streaming of video from https, I'm using html5 video tag and playing the video by : myVid.play().

Comment: If that worked, then the device isn't trusting the server certificate, you can use another root certificate to sign your server certificate (like geotrust or verisign), or you can use a plugin to open the video instead of using the html5 video tag

Comment: So is it only by using another root certificate(known one) to sign my server certificate that i can make my device trust it?

Comment: Well, some other things might work, like on the SystemWebViewClient class, changing the onReceiveSslError to @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }. This should override ssl errors on requests and the video might work. But the best solution is to use a trusted certificate